# web scraping : getting data behind a chart

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I wish to download the historical data behind the slider chart on the webpage. any python script ? and how do we identify the data behind the slider charts/tables? here's the website: https://opstra.definedge.com/ivchart and https://traderslounge.in/ivrank-JETAIRWAYS/

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
r = requests.get('https://traderslounge.in/ivrank-JETAIRWAYS/')
da=str(date.today())
Data=pd.DataFrame(r.json()["data"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can fetch this data directly from their api without scraping.
For example insert this into your URL bar an hit enter https://tools.traderslounge.in/optionsdashboardapp/iv/NIFTY
It is a get request. I tried with the fetch API from a different tab and I got no CORS issues. You can see where this page is getting its data from when you examine the pages network activity.

```
press f12 on the page to open the dev tools -> 
open the network pane ->
refresh the page ->
examine requests named NIFTY ->
copy url form headers pane ->
make your own request from python with the requests package,
that you seem to know already.
```

*Note the response is json.*

[image]
[image]

I did not 100% test on the second URL but I think you want to get this (which gives also no CORS error)
https://traderslounge.in/FNO/ivrank/JETAIRWAYS_IV.json

Comment: how did you get the dark mode in the network tab please?